# How to identify the leaf nodes of a binary search tree

Tags: arrays, algorithm, tree

I recently came across the following problem that was said to have been asked in a technical interview:

> Given the preorder traversal of a binary search tree, how do we identify the leaf nodes without building the tree?

E.g: [5,3,2,4,8,7,9]

The question was left vague by whoever posted it and given the vagueness, I'm not really sure what the approach should be for this one and I haven't been able to find verified solutions online.

**How should this problem be solved?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider your example :  `[5,3,2,4,8,7,9]`

Take the first element : `5`.

Since this is a **preorder traversal** that's **root node** for sure.

Now, in preorder traversal, after root u recur for **left subtree** and then **right subtree**.

And u also know that in **BST** :

```
 nodes in left subtree < root < nodes in right subtree
```

Hence after 5, all the elements in series **which are less than 5** belongs to **left subtree**. And similarly for right.

So u end up having this **(you don't need to explicitly create tree)** :

```
        5
     /    \
  [3,2,4] [8,7,9]
```

Now `[3,2,4]` is preorder traversal for left subtree part and `[8,7,9]` for right.

Recurse for both sub-arrays and the moment u are left with array of size 1, that's the leaf.

Comment: This approach seems correct although it is based on the assumption that the tree is perfect and complete as suggested in another answer.

Comment: I don't think the tree needs to perfect or complete. For ex : for [2,3] , this is not a perfect tree but algorithm works for it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume we consider only [*perfect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees) BSTs. Because if it is not perfect, there can be (possibly) multiple answers.

So looking at the examples and description of [preorder traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order) it is obvious that roots are taken first and then it 'does down' to leaves. As we have a perfect tree then we can see that leaves are always going in pairs. And also we need to 'skip' their parents.

Intuitively I would suggest going backwards, as 2 last elements are leaves ('*' denotes not leaves):

`[*,*,2,4,*,7,9]` <-- The overal procedure is as follows (going backwards):

1. take 2 leaves;
2. skip 1 node (their parent);
3. repeat steps [1-2];
4. skip 1 more node (parent of parents);
5. done (there is no more elements left).

Now demo on a larger array (15 elements, again perfect tree):

`[*,*,*,l,l,*,l,l,*,*,l,l,*,l,l]` <-- where `l` denotes a leaf. Steps (also backwards):

1. 1-4 from prevoius example;
2. again 1-4 from previous example;
3. skip 1 more node (parent of parents of parents);
4. done (no more elements).

Hope, you got an idea.

As for programmatical approach, you can spot a repeating pattern in above intuitive approach and use a recursion depending on the height of the tree (can be easilly computed as `log2(n+1)` where `n` is number of elements in tree, also look [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Properties_of_binary_trees)) but probably starting from the beginning of the array. Pseudocode:

```
void getLeaves(int height) {
    if (height == 2) {       // there is only a parent and two childs (leaves)
        skip(1);             // skip 1 element
        take(2);             // next two are leaves, get them
    }
    else {
        skip(1);             // skip parent of parents (of parents ...)
        getLeaves(height-1); // call on left part of array
        getLeaves(height-1); // call on right part of array
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to make use of the BST property as suggested in another answer.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a "perfect" BST and still there will only one answer. Because there is only one pre-order traversal for a BST. So we can't be going backwards and finding leaf nodes. Consider pre-order traversal 899, 999, 1099, there is only one leaf node.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PreorderArrayToTree {

    static void printLeafNodes(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        if(list.size()==0)return;
        if(list.size()==1) {
            System.out.print(list.get(0)+" ");
            return;
        }
        int parent = list.get(0);
        ArrayList<Integer> leftChild = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> rightChild =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=1; i<list.size(); i++) {
            if(list.get(i)<parent)leftChild.add(list.get(i));
            if(list.get(i)>parent)rightChild.add(list.get(i));
        };
        printLeafNodes(leftChild);
        printLeafNodes(rightChild);
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //int[] arr  = {10,5,1,7,40,50};
        //int[] arr =  {890, 325, 290, 530, 965};
        int[] arr = {3,2,4};
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)list.add(arr[i]);
        printLeafNodes(list);
    };
};
```

Comment: You should add explanations how your code solves the question.

Answer (score -2):

```
void printleafnode(int*arr, int size)
{
    int i = 0;

    while(i < size)
    {
        if(arr[i] > arr[i+1])
            i= i+1;
        else
        {
            if(arr[i] < arr[i+1])
            {
                printf(" %d " ,arr[i]);
                i= i+1;
            }
         }
    }
    printf(" %d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I formatted your code block, but it still lacks any explanation, which makes it a not very helpful answer.

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, this question was asked 6 **months** ago, and already had an accepted solution. Please try to avoid bumping questions to the top by providing answers to them, unless the question was not already marked as resolved, or you found a new and improved solution to the problem. Also remember to provide some [**context surrounding your code**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) to help explain it. Check out the documentation on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)

Comment: copy paste from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/leaf-nodes-preorder-binary-search-tree/